# Context switch in module's function execute

Tags: module, linux-kernel

I read that when you run module, the code becomes part of the kernel. But I figured that there can be context switch between processes while module's function is still executing. How could it be? I read that there are no context switches while in kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly there are context switches in the Linux kernel. It's [called kernel pre-emption](http://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/Preemption). I'm not sure where you read that there are no context-switches in the kernel or why you'd think it's impossible.

A kernel thread (presumably where your module code will be executing on) is scheduled just like any other user thread.

Answer (score 0):

But the question seems incorrect.

> But I figured that there can be context switch between processes while module's function is still executing.

What?

Say we have a module which implements a filesystem. If you open a file on such a filesystem through open syscall, the code goes open -> some lookups -> **the code in the module**. All of this is happening in the context of **the same thread**. There is no concept of **module context**. It may be the code in the module created some kernel threads on its own, but this has zero relation to it being a module.

Answer (score 0):

process could run in one of these context at any given point of time :

1. user mode
2. kernel mode
3. Interrupt mode

Context switch happens in all cases. In Interrupt mode, it is programmer responsibility to disable context switch on the CPU while executing top half section of the interrupt. I dont know where you read that context switching do not happen in kernel mode.